# CGRect function is not working while placing image in textfield

Tags: ios, image, uitextfield, cgrect, leftview

I am trying to set image inside the textfield , and for that i am creating an image view in code but when i am trying to adjust its width and height via CGRect(x:int, y:int, width:int, height:int) , its not being applied and the image size is still original. I ve seen so many tutorials for putting image in text field and all of them are using CGRect and its working for them, as size of image gets what they apply in CGRect, but not for me. Below is the code i m trying to use. Image is also attached. Textfield style is rounded (Default) and icon size is 50px.
[image: enter image here]

UIViewController

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    update()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func update() {
    email.leftViewMode = .always
    let imageview = UIImageView()
    let image = UIImage(named: "icon")
    imageview.image = image
    imageview.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: 50 , height: 50)
    email.leftView = imageview
}
```

}

Also, i ve tried to change 'Render as' to 'template' in image assets but its still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I’ve tried to do it programmatically and it works for me. Quickly drafted it on iPad playgrounds. Try this:

```
class Test: UIViewController {

let lable = UITextField()
let image = UIImage()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    lable.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 300 , height: 50)
    lable.backgroundColor = .black
    update()
    self.view.addSubview(lable)
}

func update() {
    lable.leftViewMode = .always
    let imageview = UIImageView()
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "icloud")
    imageview.image = image
    imageview.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: 50 , height: 50)
    lable.leftView = imageview
    self.view.addSubview(imageview)
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply brother! I know your answer is correct and it surely is working on your device, but i cant seem to figure out what the heck is wrong with my machine . Your peice of code is also not working on my device. I am missing something and i cant figure out . :/